# Choppy video in all browsers

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

I recently defragged and ran the hard disk error checking provided with windows xp on. Since then when I watch streamed videos such as youtube the video is really choppy.

I am running windows XP and have tried using IE, firefox and chrome and the problem persists across all three. Does anyone have any suggestions to stop this or any idea why defragging or error checking could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the defragging or error checking caused it and it's just a coincidence.

The reason it persists in all browsers is that the problem is related to XP and your video driver.

I would try these items, in this order:

1. Update display driver, possibly seeing if an update is available in Windows Update.
2. Use the autoruns program from sysinternals.com (now on microsoft.com) and see what's running when you boot up.  You might have a bunch of cruft running sucking the life out of your windows.
3. Look in the task manager to make sure there aren't programs running taking a bunch of your CPU's juice.  That could also cause choppy video.